# How to select rows from MS-SQL server and show them in Gridview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio, android-layout

This is the code I am using to connect to MS-SQL server database and select a specific row based on ID and show it in Gridview in Android.

Database has 5 columns [CID],[customerName],[type],[status],[reply].
Problem : It only selects and show name row TWICE and nothing else , I have checked and re-checks and but I cant seem to find the problem.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<Model> itemArrayList;  //List items Array
//private SyncData.MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter;
//private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter;
private GridView gridView; // GridView
private boolean success = false; // boolean
Connection con;
String ip = "192.168.121.32";
String db = "CMS";
String un = "cms";
String pass = "cms";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    itemArrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    //new MainActivity.SyncData().execute("");
    SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
    orderData.execute("");

}

private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String msg = "Internet/DB_Credentials/Windows_FireWall_TurnOn Error, See Android Monitor in the bottom For details!";
    ProgressDialog progress;
    String z="";
    Boolean Success = false;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            con = connectionClass(un,pass,db,ip);
            if(con == null){
                Success=false;
            }
            else {
                try {
                    String sql = "SELECT [CID],[customerName],[type],[status],[reply] FROM Table_1 WHERE CID='" + 1 + "' ";

                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (rs!=null) {
                       while (rs.next()){
                           try {
                               itemArrayList.add(new Model(rs.getInt("CID"),rs.getString("customerName"),rs.getString("type"),
                                       rs.getString("status"),rs.getString("reply")));



                           }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();

                           }
                           msg = "Found";
                           success = true;

                       }
                    } else {
                        msg = "No Data found!";
                        success = false;


                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                    msg = writer.toString();
                    success = false;
                }
            }
            return msg;
        }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Synchronising",
                "GridView Loading! Please Wait...", true);
    }
    private MyAppAdapter myAppAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (success == false)
        {
        }
        else {
            try {
                myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemArrayList, MainActivity.this);
                gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                gridView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
    }
    public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        public class ViewHolder{
            TextView cid;
            TextView customerName;
            TextView type;
            TextView status;
            TextView reply;
        }
        public List<Model> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<Model> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<Model> apps, Context context)
        {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<Model>();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return  parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View rowView = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder= null;
            if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.cid=rowView.findViewById(R.id.cid);
            viewHolder.customerName= rowView.findViewById(R.id.customerName);
            viewHolder.type= rowView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            viewHolder.status= rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            viewHolder.reply= rowView.findViewById(R.id.reply);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);}
            else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.cid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.customerName.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.type.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.status.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.reply.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName());

            return rowView;
        }
    }


    }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionClass(String user, String password, String database, String server){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String connectionURL = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server+"/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("SQL Connection Error : ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return connection;
}



}
```

Comment: DO NOT directly connect to a database like this in a released app.  TO do so, you need to put your db password in the app, which means you have no data security AT ALL.  Instead, write a webservice that goes between your db and your android app.

Comment: Thanks , this still has a long way to go and I do not plan of using the current database connection.

Comment: As for the problem with your SQL-  what's the CID on those 5 rows?  You do have a where clause that could be filtering them out.  What do you get if you connect via terminal and query the DB with the same command?

Comment: CID is an auto generated integer within the database, an identity column, yes I have tried it with a where clause and the output is the same, it only displays names column twice and nothing else. For instance if the name column have John in it , it will fetch John twice and no other data related to the CID.